# не работает .htaccess :(

Tags: php, .htaccess, openserver

Что только я не писал в файле .htaccess... Задача очень простая: нужно чтобы нельзя было открыть другие папки и файлы лежащие рядом с index.php и прочитать их. Так как там и папка images и templates и вообще много всякой информации не для широкой общественности. Вместо этого просто перенаправлять все запросы на index.php. Сейчас файл выглядит так:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Файл точно запускается, так как если все удалить и написать набор беспорядочных символов - выдается ошибка Server error! Error 500. С данным кодом сайт работает, но я могу залезть в любую папку рядом. Пытаюсь это все провернуть на OpenServer.

Comment: Сайт запускаете на локалке или на хостинге?
На локалке .htaccess не работает.

Comment: @ДаниилЛисов с чего это?

Comment: на локалке запускаю

Comment: на нескольких видео в ютуб тоже на локальном сервере запускают, вроде работает у них. Тоже OpenServer. но у меня ни под каким предлогом не хочет

Comment: В настойках сервера выключена возможность изменения настроек через файлы .htaccess. Включите её

Comment: Мне только одно непонятно. Почему автор вопроса решил, что вышеприведённый код имеет **хоть какое-то, хоть малейшее отношение** к тому, что "можно залезть в любую папку рядом". То есть как всегда - проблема про одно, а вопрос СОВСЕМ про другое, не имеющее к проблеме вообще никакого отношения. И теперь иди знай - на какой вопрос отвечать - на тот который был задан, или решать проблему, которая на самом деле.

Comment: @Ипатьев файл .htaccess у автора **не игнорируется**. Вынужден откатить вашу правку как противоречащую намерениям автора, а вопрос просто должен быть закрыт как непонятный.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess работает если сервер запущен только для севера Apache. Проверьте, какой веб-сервер используется у вас.

Кроме этого, в Apache за работу .htaccess отвечает настройка `AllowOverride` которая должна быть выставлена в значение `On`.